# $H:=\{ g^2 : g \in G \}$ is a subgroup of $G$ $\implies $ $H$ is normal in $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group . If $H :=\{ g^2 : g \in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ , the how to prove that $H$ is normal in $G$ ?

Comment: Looks like it would be characteristic!

Comment: And ... the commutator subgroup $G' \subseteq H$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider if $h\in G$ then $h^2 \in H$, so for any $g\in G$ we have:

$$gh^2g^{-1} = (ghg^{-1})^2 \in H$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What is $(hgh^{-1})^n$ equal to, for any $n$?

Comment: Note that $g$ could not have a finite order. Consider $G = \mathbb{Q}-\lbrace0\rbrace$. $H$ is indeed a subgroup but $\frac{1}{4} \in H$ has no finite order.

Comment: @DarthGeek I wasn't meaning to imply that $g$ had finite order - I just wanted the OP to realised what $(hgh^{-1})$ was equal to. But I have amended my hint to make this clearer.